# NextJS keeps re-optimizing images on load

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In my project, I want to display a gallery of images. They are all passed through either the `next/image` or `next/future/image` component (both of which have this problem), and are optimizing on load - as expected.

The issue is that they repeatedly optimize when I refresh, continually causing cold-start behaviors.

The image URL is passed into the component from `getStaticProps`, should it should remain the same. The data is fetched from a CMS.

Here is an excerpt of the code (using `next/future/image`):

```
<Image
 src={image.data.attributes.url}
 width={width}
 height={height}
 alt={alt || ""}
 className={className} // Not used with `next/image`
 {...(priority && { priority })}
/>
```

Of course, I've tried with the standard `next/image` component multiple times, removing the `className`, adding the `layout` props, etc. Same behavior.

I see image files being cached in `./next/cache/images/<imageUUID>/`, so the files persist. When in a docker container, I make sure to attach a volume to it. Either way, it happens in and outside of a docker container.

When reloading the page using <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, going between the pages, and switching browsers/devices, the CPU usage jumps every couple of reloads as the site loads slower - with the images trying to load in:

[image: Docker container CPU usage after reloading]

I've seen it go as high as 2600% on my local machine, which would effectively lock my EC2 instance.

I'd expect the CPU usage to be high when I first visit the page after starting a fresh app build, but this repeatedly happens as I visit the site. On my machine, the speed is bearable. But when deployed to an AWS EC2 instance, it makes it unusable.

Here is my NextJS config:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: ["picsum.photos", "<mys3>.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"],
  },
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en"],
    defaultLocale: "en",
  },
  experimental: { images: { allowFutureImage: true } },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

And my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@apollo/client": "^3.6.9",
  "classnames": "^2.3.1",
  "graphql": "^16.5.0",
  "next": "^12.2.2",
  "next-themes": "^0.2.0",
  "react": "18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "18.2.0",
  "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
  "react-spinners": "^0.13.3",
  "sharp": "^0.30.7"
},
```

Without `sharp`, my RAM usage increases so much, and most of it even *persists* after image optimization, crashing my app via `SIGKIL` because of memory limits in EC2. I thought it was a memory leak on my end, so I inspected it with Node inspector. Could only see the built-in `squoosh` package from NextJS taking up the memory. Switching to sharp has since fixed that issue. I'm utterly at a loss as to why these issues would occur in the first place.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I have the same problem and I am force to add `unoptimized: true` in my `next.config.js` to make it go away (which of course beats the purpose of having the nice optimised next/image).

Comment: Did you find a solution to it? I'm facing the same problem.